# Не может обработать исключение AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, исключения, c++-cli

```
Приложение: GTA5.exe
Версия платформы: v4.0.30319
Описание. Процесс был завершен из-за необработанного исключения.
Сведения об исключении: System.AccessViolationException
   в nativeCall()
   в GTA.Native.NativeTask.Run()
   в GTA.ScriptDomain.DoTick()
   в GTA.ScriptDomain.DoTick()
   в <Module>.ManagedTick()
```

Вот тут вызывается сам *nativeCall*

```
private ref struct NativeTask : IScriptTask
{
    ScriptDomain a;
    virtual void Run()
    {
        try {
            nativeInit(_hash);

            for each (auto argument in _arguments)
            {
                nativePush64(argument->_data);
            }

            _result = nativeCall();
        }
        catch (AccessViolationException ^ex) {
            a.LogStatic("[Exception]", String::Concat("ScriptDomain DoTick: ", ex));
        }
    }

    UInt64 _hash, *_result;
    array<InputArgument ^> ^_arguments;
};
```

Вызывается где-то тут

```
void ScriptDomain::DoTick()
{
    try {
        // Execute scripts
        for each (Script ^script in _runningScripts)
        {
            if (!script->_running)
            {
                continue;
            }

            _executingScript = script;

            while ((script->_running = SignalAndWait(script->_continueEvent, script->_waitEvent, 30000)) && _taskQueue->Count > 0)
            {
                _taskQueue->Dequeue()->Run();
            }

            _executingScript = nullptr;

            if (!script->_running)
            {
                Log("[ERROR]", "Script '", script->Name, "' is not responding! Aborting ...");
                AbortScript(script);
                continue;
            }
        }

        // Clean up pinned strings
        CleanupStrings();
    }
    catch (AccessViolationException ^ex) {
        Log("[Exception]", "ScriptDomain DoTick: " + ex);
    }
}
```

Тупо крашит и никаких исключений не выдает.

Для ясности, использую это: https://github.com/crosire/scripthookvdotnet/tree/dev_v2

Comment: Забавно, метка `C#`, а весь предоставленный код на `C++`. Также порадовало "Тупо крашит и никаких исключений не выдает.", когда в самом начале исключение). Ну а в целом, вы ведь понимаете, что это специфический софт, для разбора которого надо вникать в то, что и как там написано. Я не думаю, что кто то будет с этим возиться, вам легче [поискать](https://github.com/crosire/scripthookvdotnet/issues?utf8=✓&q=AccessViolationException) на странице проекта или спросить у самого автора.

Comment: Тфу ты, с метками напутал. Там C# + C++. Спасибо, но надеюсь кто-то откликнется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В .NET 4.0 по умолчанию нельзя поймать некоторые виды исключений, так вызываемые Corrupted State Exceptions. Но можно разрешить конкретному методу ловить такие исключения, поставив на него атрибут `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]`

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
virtual void Run()
{
...
}
```

Обратите внимание, что рантайм при это пропустит выполнение finally-блоков (включая неявные finally в using), в методах, на которых этот атрибут не стоит:

> If a suitable catch clause is found, the CLR will unwind the stack as normal but will only execute finally and fault blocks (and in C#, the implicit finally block of a using statement) in functions marked with the attribute.

Альтернативное решение, если код поменять не получается по каким-либо причинам - собрать ваш exe / dll под 3.5, и при запуске под 4.0 добавить в конфиге

```
<legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true"/>
```

Подробное описание механизма и особенностей разных версий: [CLR Inside Out - Handling Corrupted State Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx#Four)

Comment: Пытаюсь повесить на него атрибут, пишет "Атрибут не найден".
Использую NetFramework 4.5.2

Comment: @Alexander `using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx, Available since 4.0